# Последовательное воспроизведение в MediaPlayer в цикле

Tags: java, android, mediaplayer

Есть **список** звуковых файлов:

```
static int[] sounds = {R.raw.cat1, R.raw.cat2, R.raw.cat3};
```

Есть **метод** воспроизведения файла:

```
private void meowPlay(int fileName) {
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, fileName);
    mp.setLooping(false);
    mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
        }
    });
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

По **нажатию на кнопку** выполняется следующий код:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    int rand = new Random().nextInt(2);
    meowPlay(sounds[rand]);
}
```

В результате 3 аудио файла воспроизводятся **одновременно**. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать **последовательное** воспроизведение этих файлов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то у Вас не воспроизводятся 3 файла одновременно. Вы рандомите на вход число, и если числа совпадут, то одинаковые ресурсы звука наложатся сами на себе и может показаться, что воспроизводится или 1 файл или 2 или 3 файл и то зависит от процессора, может показаться, что это эффект эхо в зависимости от скорости прохождения цикла. А вообще вопрос очень интересный, здесь только через слушатель тк MediaPlayer на вход принимает только "int resId".

Переменные:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
int[] sounds;
int index;
```

Список:

```
sounds = new int[]{R.raw.cat, R.raw.supercat, R.raw.megacat};
```

Обработчик для кнопки:

```
 public void onClick (View v){
       index = 0;
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index] );
       mp.setLooping(false);
       mp.start();
       mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
               if(index < sounds.length-1){
                   index++;
                   mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[index]);
                   mp.start();
                   mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
               }
               else mp.release();
           }
       });

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Подскажите пожалуйста, а как лучше реализовать именно случайное воспроизведение из списка? Если количество воспроизводимых файлов тоже случайно.

Comment: Вы опишите логику, как вы хотите сделать, я постараюсь ответить, не угадывать же сидеть.

Comment: Я уже придумал примерный алгоритм, только выглядит он, как мне кажется, не самым лучшим образом. Есть количество повторений: `final int count = new Random().nextInt(25);`
Сделал вот такое условие в обработчике нажатия
`if (index <= count) {
  index++;
  int rand = new Random().nextInt(23);
  mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), sounds[rand]);
  mp.start();
  mp.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}
else mp.release();`

Comment: Да вы на словах напишите пожалуйста. Пример: Я хочу чтоб из списка моих звуков выбирался случайный звук и после этого все остальные звуи воспроизводились в случайном порядке, последовательно друг за другом. так?

Comment: Немного не так. Хочу чтобы из списка, в котором допустим 25 элементов, случайным образом выбиралось случайное количество звуков для воспроизведения.

Answer (score 1):

Вам надо:

1. Убрать цикл, вызывать метод один раз.
2. Запускать следующую песню в `onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)`

Comment: Запускать понятно, но как именно перебирать массив аудио?

Comment: @McDaggen, например ввести переменную-счётчик в коей хранить текущую позицию в массиве аудио. После завершения трека её инкременировать и брать из массива следующий трек по индексу